# How do i check for all numbers

Tags: jquery, arrays, wordpress

I am using the followin jquery code for a simple product details switch.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                    var numberArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,18];
                    $.each(numberArray, function(index, value) {
                        $('.thumbs-' + value + ' img').hover(function() {
                            var url = $(this).attr('src');
                            $('#main-' + value).attr('src', url);
                        });
                    });
                });
```

But now i notice the numberArray might not the right way. The numberArray represents the product ID in my wordpress setup. Each  product id is rendered when a product is uploaded.

How can i make numberArray to represent all numbers or how should i edit the function??? I like numberArray to represent all numbers, lets say 1-xxxxxx t

html code

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="product  col-md-8 service-image-left">
    <center>
      <img id="main-18" src="http://localhost/..../site/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/warrior-bros.jpg" alt=""></img>
    </center>
  </div>

  <div class="container thumbs-18 col-md-4">
    <center>
      <a id="item-1" class="service1-item">
        <img src="http://localhost/..../site/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/warrior-bros.jpg" alt="warrior-bros"></img>
      </a>

      <a id="item-2" class="service1-item">
        <img src="http://localhost/.../site/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/frere-good.jpg" alt="frere-good"></img>
      </a>
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
```

regards

Comment: What you're asking is unclear. What do you want to get? Where is the problem?

Comment: You want to select all elements with a class prefix `thumbs-`, e.g., `.thumbs-3`, `.thumbs-09`, `.thumbs-339`?

Comment: i like numberArray to represent all numbers, lets say 1-xxxxxx that is i don't know what the product id will be.

Comment: @alex Does `numberArray` contain items other than `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5,18]` ?

Comment: `$('[class*=thumbs-] img').hover(...);` as selector?!  This would avoid the use of the each loop and hardcoded numbered array. Now to target specific `#main-*`, you should post relevant HTML markup in question

Comment: @alex how do you get `numberArray`?

Comment: Is your *actual* question "how to find the minimum and maximum number in an array"?

Comment: So what you really want is the #main-??? src to equal the .thumbs-??? url on hover?

Comment: @guest271314 no just numbers,  IIia for testing purpose i just populated by hand. Brian yes!

Comment: It's clear what Alex wants. As he already said, he wants to select all `img`elements that have an ancestor with a class starting by `.thumbs-`, i.e., `.thumbs-NUMBER`. Then when mouse hovers that image we should extract that NUMBER to find the `#main-NUMBER` in order to copy the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('div[class*=thumbs-] img').hover(function() {
      var $thisImg = $(this),
          // travel up the DOM until we find the first ancestor with a thumbs-NUMBER class and extract such number
          thumbsClass = $thisImg.
                 closest($('div[class*=thumbs-]')).
                 attr('class').
                 split(' ').
                 filter(function(c) {
                    return c.indexOf('thumbs-') === 0;
                 });

      if (thumbsClass.length === 1) {
         var suffixNumber = thumbsClass[0].replace(/thumbs-/, ''); 
         $('#main-' + suffixNumber).attr('src', $thisImg.attr('src'));
      } 
  });
});
```

The selector `[class^=thumbs-]` finds all elements that have a class starting with `thumbs-`.

I am not checking the suffix in `.thumbs-SUFFIX` to see if it is really a number. You can add a regexp to do that, but I don't think it is necessary, because if for example, a `.thumbs-world` is caught, probably there is not a `#main-world` to match against.

Comment: i am trying your suggestion but the thumbs- selector doesn't work
 $('[class^=thumbs-] img').hover(function() {
                    alert('hover ');`

i am updating my question with more html

Comment: Ok, now I see why it doesn't work. Your element does not start with `thumbs` class. It starts with `container`instead. FIX: replace `[class^=thumbs-]` by `[class*=thumbs-]`

Comment: you got a winner! still i have two questions what is the difference between class^ vs class* ? 2nd question see my answer

Answer (score 0):

After editing Jose original solution i got this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                    $('[class*=thumbs-] img').hover(function() {
                        var $thisImg = $(this);                  
                        // travel up the DOM until we find the first ancestor with a thumbs-NUMBER class and extract such number
                        suffixNumber = $thisImg.closest($('[class*=thumbs-]')).attr('class').replace(/thumbs-/, '').replace(/col-md-4/, '').replace(/container/, '');
                        console.log(suffixNumber);
                         console.log('test '+$thisImg.attr('src'));
    //                    $('#main-18').attr('src', $thisImg.attr('src'));
                        $('#main-' + suffixNumber).attr('src', $thisImg.attr('src'));
                    });
                });
```

But only the last line didn't work, although suffixNumber equals 18 ( Console.log displays 18 for suffixNumber)?? When hardcoding #main-18 it did work.

Comment: Use my updated code, that splits the multiples classes and extracts only the thumbs class. Your code fails, because in reality what you see in console is not "18", but " 18 " instead.

Comment: `[class^=thumbs-]` matches elements with a class **beginning** with the string `thumbs-`.`[class*=thumbs-]` matches elements with a class **containing** the string `thumbs-`.

Comment: THANK YOU for being so kind to give an explanation. I didn't notice the spaces around 18, i got rid of it by using .replace(' ',''). But i am going for your solution!